# Multivariable, quadratic ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Subject to some initial conditions, is there a closed form for the ordinary differential equation
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1x_1^2 + a_2x_1x_2 + a_3x_2^2 \\ b_1x_1^2 + b_2x_1x_2 + b_3x_2^2 \end{bmatrix}, $$
where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are constant? More generally, I'm wondering when the ODE
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1' \\ \vdots \\ x_n' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x^TM_1x \\ \vdots \\ x^TM_nx \end{bmatrix} $$
has a closed form solution, where the square matrices $M_i$ here are constant. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291684/quadratic-ode-systems

Comment: thanks, and apologies for the duplicate!